# Packard Bell VAB70 keyboard & touchpad not working

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, keyboard, touchpad

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a Packard Bell VAB70 laptop. Initially I installed 12.04, during the installation process the touchpad & keyboard worked, so I was able to enter the wi-fi key. However on completion of the installation both do not work. I subsequently installed 14.04 64 bit, and the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

6 years and two months later, I stumbled upon the same problem (beside a few functions keys, the keyboard and touchpad are unusable under Linux Mint/Ubuntu 20).

For the posterity, I found that upgrading the BIOS to it's latest version (1.10, released on 2011-12-19) solved the issue!

### Notes

I downloaded the driver from the download center, in the support section, at https://www.packardbell.com/.

On this site, **VAB70** yield zero results; if you do not want to search by Serial Number or SNID, the product can be found under the reference EasyNote **LK11BZ**.

The archive is named `BIOS_PackardBell_1.10_A_A.zip`.

The `SHABV110.exe` will flash *from* a running Microsoft Windows.
I did not try the `Update.bat` from a FreeDOS or similar environment.

#### Checksums

MD5

```
5ccada9d9dec8443466ba6745d0ed943  ./BIOS_PackardBell_1.10_A_A.zip
ef58f5d68616190d882621d98732459a  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/DOS/flashit.exe
b65333b6c8810c4e068e0c59483d745d  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/DOS/Update.bat
7b4ac9dc2928931ead357bd6c9e9e5d6  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/DOS/SHABV110.FD
025e2c6f894b95ec544c26f014ad5b3c  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/Windows/SHABV110.exe
117059c0347ae37ef1bcc2e54b378c6c  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/readme.txt
```

SHA256:

```
c6bb3f5a43a19e1b1e9fd71522b0cc2c679d5f82abc82bfe46a7ecdbe2df1335  ./BIOS_PackardBell_1.10_A_A.zip
97b43dc375d65a3eecb6f7e2dc24f7b10fd20e1c3dba4e1c62ea6a33a344b1b9  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/DOS/flashit.exe
2c97ae51c297f2c18e5dcbf30576615876d0c132fef0d41883cecb9f8162575f  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/DOS/Update.bat
97f4d89f503058c61e80e297ae805580c1f278eb46aa38e4c10aeeb219147d5f  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/DOS/SHABV110.FD
7aa337d3177798a7e576eb89031ceedb4c0addc51b579027ada804667ac29e6b  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/Windows/SHABV110.exe
45a250af68fd6592f3d578578717114c2ecedf0d02efc7bf50b7c04ab60e54a4  ./BIOS_Packard Bell_1.10_Windows/readme.txt
```